# Are characters within the same tag but before CDATA tag taken into account?

Tags: xml, cdata

I ran into an unexpected error parsing a XML-in-XML document, that uses CDATA. It seems I fixed the problem by removing the whitespace and comment before, but inside of the same tag, as the CDATA-data. Why is this happening?

Doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ValidationRequest>
    <XMLDocument>
    <!-- The XML to check is placed here in CDATA -->
    <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Order>
        <!-- Order example -->
        <ID>123</cbc:ID>
        </Order>]]>
    </XMLDocument>
</ValidationRequest>
```

Works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ValidationRequest>
    <XMLDocument><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Order>
        <!-- Order example -->
        <ID>123</cbc:ID>
        </Order>]]>
    </XMLDocument>
</ValidationRequest>
```

I'm deserializing the (outer) XML object using Jackson, where the XMLDocument attribute is deserialized as a String type, for later processing. I'm validating that against a schema feeding the XML String as an input stream.
This is the part of the deserialization annotation about this element:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ValidationRequest")
public class ValidationRequest {
    @XmlElement(name="XMLDocument")
    public String xmlDocument;
...
```

I expect both to work, but the first example gave the following error.
`ParseError at [row,col]:[4,8]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.`

The second example works, but my question is why?

Comment: Neither example is well-formed, because the CDATA section is opened but never closed. So I suspect you haven't shown us the real data.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it, I believe.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gerozapoko/1/edit?js,console — Cannot reproduce, both versions work.

Comment: Both examples are now well-formed. You need to give us more information about exactly what you are doing to trigger this error.

Comment: Aah, maybe the problem is in the deserializing. I deserialize it to a String first, and then feeding this plain String into a SAX parser.